# $g'(x) \ge f'(x)$ implies $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Conjecture:

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $g'(x) \ge f'(x)$ for all $x \in(a,b)$ then $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is decreasing in $(a,b)$ if $h(x)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$.

---

I came up with this myself when I was studying the nature of functions however I don't know if it's true. (It seems very obvious intuitively)

---

$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.
To prove $h'(x) < 0$ for $ x \in(a,b)$ 
$h'(x ) = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$

To prove: $g(x)f'(x) < f(x)g'(x)$

Here I don't know what to continue with.

---

Some examples:

If $g(x) = k$(Constant function) and $k$ is not $0$

$\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x \in (0 , \infty)$ or $x \in (-\infty,0)$

I found many other examples but no counterexamples.

Any counterexample in case this is not true will help.

Comment: You have to make assumptions on the signs of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some assumptins are missing. A counter-example is $f(x)=x-1$ and $g(x)=2x$ in which case $h$ is increasing.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to conclude "in a positive way" (pun intended) to your question if supplementary assumptions are made, i.e.,

$$    \forall x \in (a,b) \ \ \begin{cases}\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{<}&f'(x)&<&g'(x)\\ \color{red}{0}&\color{red}{<}&\color{red}{g(x)} &\color{red}{<}&\color{red}{f(x)}\end{cases}$$

As the involved quantities are all positive, we are allowed to multiply the two second inequations, giving:

$$g(x)f'(x) < f(x)g'(x) $$

i.e., $ \ g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x) < 0$ as desired.